# Why is the animation twitching?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to implement a running line animation, but I'm faced with the fact that, despite the smoothness of the animation, it starts to twitch from time to time (I don't confuse this with restarting the animation). This is visible on the full screen.

I have already tried to implement both on pure CSS, React libraries, and on pure JS. Everything works fine, but everywhere the result is that the animation twitches when moving. What could this be related to?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wevuj.jpg

```js
const block = document.getElementById("block")
block.animate([
  // keyframes
  { transform: 'translate3D(0, 0, 0)' },
  { transform: `translate3D(-10000px, 0, 0)` }
], {
  // timing options
  duration: 16000,
  iterations: Infinity
});
```

```css
#block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.elem {
  height: 50px;
}
.a1 {
  min-width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
.a2 {
    min-width: 150px;
  background: black;
}
.a3 {
    min-width: 74px;
  background: blue;
}
.a4 {
    min-width: 223px;
  background: purple;
}
.a5 {
    min-width: 800px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div class="elem a1"></div>
  <div class="elem a2"></div>
  <div class="elem a3"></div>
  <div class="elem a4"></div>
  <div class="elem a5"></div>
  <div class="elem a1"></div>
  <div class="elem a2"></div>
  <div class="elem a3"></div>
  <div class="elem a4"></div>
  <div class="elem a5"></div>
  <div class="elem a1"></div>
  <div class="elem a2"></div>
  <div class="elem a3"></div>
  <div class="elem a4"></div>
  <div class="elem a5"></div>
  <div class="elem a1"></div>
  <div class="elem a2"></div>
  <div class="elem a3"></div>
  <div class="elem a4"></div>
  <div class="elem a5"></div>
  <div class="elem a1"></div>
  <div class="elem a2"></div>
  <div class="elem a3"></div>
  <div class="elem a4"></div>
  <div class="elem a5"></div>
  <div class="elem a1"></div>
  <div class="elem a2"></div>
  <div class="elem a3"></div>
  <div class="elem a4"></div>
  <div class="elem a5"></div>
  <div class="elem a1"></div>
  <div class="elem a2"></div>
  <div class="elem a3"></div>
  <div class="elem a4"></div>
  <div class="elem a5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It might be a hardware issue. The demo does not twitch for me

Comment: @evolutionxbox try use the chrome browser

Comment: Nope, Chrome is fine

Comment: @Paulie_D https://imgur.com/2K6GEl9 You can see it here

Comment: Doesn't help, its working fine on my laptop in Chrome so it does sound like a hardware issue.